# C++ Morse Code translator, my program kept crashing

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char option;
int choice;
string str;

string text[39] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
        "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","STOP",",","?"};
string morse[39] = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.",
                    "--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",
                    ".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----",".-.-.-","--..--","..--.."};

do{
    system("cls");

    cout << "1. Encode(Text to Morse)\n";
    cout << "2. Decode(Morse Code to Text)\n";
    cout << "3. Display the Morse Code\n";
    cout << "4. Quit\n";
    cout << "\nEnter a number 1-4: ";
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
       {
        cout << "Enter text: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,str);

        cout << "\n";
        cout << "The target string to be translated is:";
        cout << str;


        cout << "\n\nNumber of characters in the string is "<<str.length();
        cout << "\nIn Morse the message is:\n";
        int i; //string position  counter
        int a; //morse code finder loop counter

        i = 0;
        while (i<str.length())  //to loop every single position in the string.
        {
            a = 0;

            if((str[i] >= 'a') && (str[i] <= 'z'))   // upcase everything
                str[i] = toupper(str[i]);

            string n = "";
            n += str[i];     // convert str[i] (a char) to string.

            while ( a<= 39 ) // to find the matching morse code to that character.
            {
                if (n == text[a])
                {
                   cout << morse[a] << " ";
                }
                a += 1;
            }

            if(str[i] == ' ')
               cout << "\n";

            i += 1;
        }

        cout << "Run this again?(y/n)\n";
        cin >> option;
       }
        break; 
       default:
}
}while((option == 'y')||(option=='Y'));
}
```

I haven't finished the rest, but this part kept crashing. I think there is something wrong with the loops. 
I cannot figure out which part went wrong..
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: don't forget the colon ---...   There are other characters.  The wiki page has a nice tree which covers the less frequently used characters.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code

Comment: Hi EvilTeach, could you help me with this problem, there is a weird error that I cannot get rid of.

Comment: I have rolled back the question because it was edited to contain substantially different code and question. To ask a new question click on "Ask Question" and post the new question.  (Although you should produce a smaller example than the pages of code you tried to post).

Comment: Sorry, I tried. But it won't let me ask another question till 2 days later. So I had to do this...

Comment: It's fine..I guess I will go another forum

Comment: It says "You've asked 2 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community"

Comment: Just because my questions didn't receive high score, I think the new system limits how often I post a new question :(

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
a<= 39
```

The size of the array is 39, so index 39 is out of bounds.

It should be:

```
a < 39
```

Comment: omg, what a silly mistake. Thank you !

Comment: A second set of eyes always helps.

Comment: I gave up after 2 hours of debugging, finally!

Comment: Hi, Stephen, could you help me with this error? This is a different one from the Morse code thing, stackoverflow won't let me post questions till 2 days later, so I had to edit the previous one.

Comment: @NathanNan If it "won't let you post questions" it should also give a message explaining what the problem is and how to fix it. Also you should accept this answer because it answered your question (as you originally posted it)

Comment: I understand, but there was nothing I could do but editing my previous question, I think the new system is biased, it limits how often you can post your question based on how high your questions' scores are. It feels like this forum is only for professional programmers, basically, they kicking out the non-professional users, it's like "Don't post your stupid questions here".